# Eclipse SVN Not show author info in compare editors

Tags: eclipse, svn

Eclipse SVN Not show author info in compare editors

OS：Mac 10.13.4
IDE：Eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0)

- Not Show author info image 
  [image]
- Right image
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the Label decorations have been turned off. Please have a look at [this document](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_label_decors.php) - check the Text Decorations section.

Comment: Thanks. But not this perspective, is **Team Synchronize** perspective.